# Leshrac the Malicious

Tags: dota

I am just wondering, is there some tips for **Leshrac the Malicious**, the guy seems to have powerful skills, but if I choose to increase the intelligence (for mana) he is too weak, increase the strength the regeneration of mana too slow, if the agility (no mana reg neither too much blood)

Comment: You need to give us more specifics. Are you playing him as a support in the lane (Helping the carry farm safely) or are you playing him as a main farmer (either solo mid, or in a dual stun lane as main farmer generally)

Answer (score 2):

OK so here's the thing with Leshrac...

First of all usually you don't need to add skill points in the lightning skill, or at least early game you don't... your skill points should go into Diabolic Edict and Split Earth(in this order). You can even skip the ultimate at level 6.

OK so now that the skills are clarified, let's talk about how to actually play with this hero... The idea is that is better to go on a side lane than mid lane, because on the middle the distance between your tower and the enemy tower is relatively small. And this matters because over the years, what I've come to see as the best strategy when playing Leshrac is wait for the moment when there are a few creeps or the creeps are low hp and then stun the target, move next to him and cast Diabolic Edict. The thing with Diabolic Edict is that you need to isolate your target and stay near him.

As for what items to buy.. at the beginning you need some strength because you are very low hp, some hp and mp regen...
good items on leshrac are bloodstone, aghanim, shiva, guinsoo, heart, travel(or in early game you can make arcane boots and dissemble then when building the bloodstone)...

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I think aghnams scepter is the choice you want to make to get all those attributes. But thats mid game item you can think of blood stone too which is much easier to make it in chunks. What you can do in the early game is to get some hp to survive in the lane which you get by bracer and mana potions. You should use your skills wisely to not get out of mana, some people just spam the skills to but its better to use them to kill if you have fragile heroes in your lane.

I can recommend some links for full guides

[dota2 video guide here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0x3DghXN1E)

[and a dota good guide here](http://www.playdota.com/guides/guide-to-the-aoe-monster)

Answer (score 0):

**Cheap / effective**

Magic Wand,
Bracer,
Drum,
Arcane boots,
Ghost Scepter

**Bigger Items**

Aghanim's Scepter, Bloodstone, Scythe of Vyse, Black King bar

In competitive games, it is normal to see a semi-carry Leshrac rushing black king bar first. Part of playing Lesh is to understand mana usage and conservation. Just practice a lot and watch pros play leshrac, and you will see there is a balance between using spells to farm creeps and spells to attack heros. Also look for how the toggle on and off their ultimate form.